# Hackerrank.com tic tac toe challenge

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, challenge-response

I want to ask is it possible to win at tic tac toe challenge? Because the judgebot knows each and every trick and he knows how to fail the trick moves . I am only able to tie the game in both turns . If it is possible , can you guys please just give me a hint ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really win at tic tac toe if both players knows how to play the game. If you start at the middle, the other player can block you out by placing it at the top then left or something. Can't really remember now but unless you break the AI it's not possible to win. Sorry :(

Comment: +1: it's a finished set of moves, if AI is well programmed cannot loose to a human being.

Comment: See also [xkcd: Tic Tac Toe](http://xkcd.com/832/) and [xkcd: Game AIs](http://xkcd.com/1002/).